# git merge looks like it's missing changes

Tags: git, merge

When doing a complex merge, I wrote some scripts to track all of the changes and help us with conflict resolution.  However, it would appear that my script says that there are files with changes that are not being merged.  E.g. file.cpp exists on both branches, doing a `git diff <commit1>..<commit2>` says there is a difference (commitN are the tips of the branches).  Separately getting the file from each branch and doing a `git diff --no-index` also shows a difference.

So, why is the merge not doing any merge for some of my files that apparently have a difference?  Is there something that I'm just not seeing as a possibility for what I think is strange behaviour?

### Diagnostics I've done

I generated a list of all of the files that didn't get merged and piped it into `xargs -I{} sh -c 'f() { echo DIFF $1; git show BRANCH-A:$1 > vA 2>&1 & git show BRANCH-B:$1 > vB 2>&1 & wait; git diff --color=always --no-index vA vB | cat; }; f {}'` and it showed that some files didn't exist and some file had changes.

Things I've looked at:

1. These two branches have a common root.
2. I've tried getting a clean clone.
3. The files are in the repo, so they're tracked.
4. We don't have any submodules that I'm aware of.
5. I've checked to see if there's a git ignore rule affecting the files. There is not.
6. I have no local hooks and the problem is occurring locally.
7. No issues with permissions.  The files that do exist are `-rw-r--r--`.
8. `git status` doesn't show the files at all, prior to adding/committing.
9. `GIT_TRACE=1 git merge <branch>` didn't show anything of use:

   ```
   01:30:47.678753 exec-cmd.c:244          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/bin
   01:30:47.692753 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git merge ACPx_Production
   01:30:47.777761 run-command.c:659       trace: run_command: git stash create
   01:30:47.913753 exec-cmd.c:244          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
   01:30:47.928755 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git stash create
   ```
10. I attempted to generate a patch and apply it with the commands (starting from <branch2>):

    ```
    git diff <branch1>..<branch2> > update.patch
    git apply update.patch
    ```

    However, when applying the patch, all I got were a lot of errors and nothing applied.  Using the `--reject` switch on `apply`, 4 of many files actually got applied, but all the files with modifications generated `.rej` files.

    Even applying to just one file that the merge didn't have any issues with results in failure.

I'm running under Windows 10.  `git version 2.42.0.windows.2`

### New info

So, it would seem that the reason why I have some files not show up is due to how git manages merges.  I think that the file got merged in before, resolving this issue, but with some magic, git realised this and decided that it wasn't needed to be done again.  It's this part that I'm not clear about.

After the merge from `branch1` to `branch2`, there were more commits put on `branch1`, which is why the diff say that there's a change, so how exactly does git make that decision?

Comment: Is this the first time you merge the branches, or have they been merged in the past already?

Comment: Are both of `git diff <commit1>...<commit2>` and  `git diff <commit2>...<commit1>` non-empty, or does one of them report no output? (Note the three dots!)

Comment: @j6t, this isn't mu first roadeo if that's that you mean. :)

Comment: @j6t, I was thinking that I should use 3 dots instead of 2, as I'm still a little confused by its use.  In any case, switching to 3 dots also showed that the merge should still have some additional files.

Comment: @j6t If you mean if the two branches were merged in the past, then yes, they were.

Comment: @j6t, just to be clear, both `git diff <commit1>...<commit2>` and `git diff <commit2>...<commit1>` generate non-empty output.  Some of the files that seem to be missing from the merge do appear in the output, with some being modified/renamed/added/deleted.

Comment: Suppose you're merging `feature` into `main`. It's possible for a file to be different on both branches, and also have output for both sides of a 3-dot diff, and *still* have no changes as a result of the merge. For example, if there are new changes on `main` to that file that aren't on `feature` yet, nothing will happen as a result of merging `feature` into `main`. Also, if there are new changes to that file on `feature`, but those same changes are also on `main` in separate commits (perhaps due to a cherry-pick), then still the merge of `feature` into `main` won't affect that file.

Comment: Obviously we can't say for sure if the scenario I described in the previous comment is what's happening in your case, but, just knowing it's possible might be enough for you to confirm if that's the case. Or, if you could isolate a single file in a minimal reproducible example it would likely help us help you troubleshoot.